# No internet for 32-bit apps on 64-bit vista

Tags: windows-vista, networking, troubleshooting, windows-update

I'm trying to help fix a machine with Vista SP1. After installing this weeks Windows Updates the 32-bit apps on the machine no longer connects to the internet. If I run the 64-bit IE then it works fine. But 32-bit IE just says it's unable to connect and results in a crash dialog when quitting it. Same with any other 32-bit app that uses the internet.

**Log entries**:

```
Program med fejl iexplore.exe, version 8.0.6001.18813, 
tidsstempel 0x4a6621ae, modul med fejl unknown, version 0.0.0.0, 
tidsstempel 0x00000000, undtagelseskode 0xc0000005, forskydning med 
fejl 0x022e17d0, proces-id 0x5ec, 
programmets starttidspunkt 0x01ca280ea90f80a5.

Program med fejl firefox.exe, version 1.9.0.3498, 
tidsstempel 0x4a728f53, modul med fejl unknown, version 0.0.0.0, 
tidsstempel 0x00000000, undtagelseskode 0xc0000005, 
forskydning med fejl 0x028d00c4, proces-id 0x324, 
programmets starttidspunkt 0x01ca27f5d8ca22f5.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access violation code "0xc0000005" (undtagelseskode) might be the clue here. In fact there's an [article](http://help.lockergnome.com/vista/Vista-x64-ping-browse-email-messenger--ftopict69855.html) where exactly the same problem was discussed.

This [article](http://www.updatexp.com/0xC0000005.html) lists common reasons for crashes with "0xc0000005" exit code. Although  the article is about Windows XP, one of the common reasons listed seems interesting, namely "Data Execution Prevention". This [article](http://www.updatexp.com/data-execution-prevention.html) looks deeper into problems caused by DEP.

Also try [searching](http://www.google.se/search?q=0xc0000005+vista) for the access violation code, it seems to be a quite popular one.

Comment: Thanks. Running 'netsh winsock reset' as pointed out in the first article solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How can you have Vista SP1 with the latest Windows Updates? Vista is currently at SP2.

If you haven't updated to SP2 do so first, as it might fix your problem.

Comment: I have no idea. It's not my machine. SP2 was listed as an 2 months old update but apparently it wasn't auto-installed.

Comment: Then installing SP2 should be the first step.